# Is having init 6 function without sudo normal or an oversight?

Tags: 16.04, sudo, reboot, systemd, init

Since I've been manually updating Ubuntu MATE 16.04 using apt update, upgrade I also manually reboot using this command `sudo init 6`

Once I forgot sudo and it worked; further testing proved that reboot and shutdown also functioned without using sudo.

I tested this using vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 and found that sudo was mandatory.

Comment: Why don't you use `reboot` and `shutdown -h now` (which are easier to remember, in my opinion)? Also, I can second your observation that `sudo` is mandatory with both `reboot`, `shutdown -h now` and `init 6` on a near-vanilla 14.04. It's not possible by default to use the aforementioned commands without `sudo`.

Comment: stated in my op  "further testing proved that reboot and shutdown also functioned without using sudo."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a design feature that since 16.04 you do no longer need root privileges to shut down or reboot the system through any method. Instead the `systemd` and its `systemctl` tool accept those commands from regular users.

All related commands like `shutdown`, `reboot`, `halt`, `poweroff` are symbolic links ("symlinks") to `/bin/systemctl` and `init` is a symlink to `/lib/systemd/systemd` now by the way. You can verify this using the command `file $(which COMMAND)`, replacing "COMMAND" with the one you want to check.

Comment: I question not your answer but the wisdom of enabling power off, shutdown, etc without sudo.

Comment: I don't really understand this decision by the developers either and I could also not find any resources about that on the web. Sorry.

Comment: Related question: [halt, poweroff, shutdown, reboot don't require root?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85359/halt-poweroff-shutdown-reboot-dont-require-root)

Comment: @MarkStosberg But that one is about Arch Linux...

Comment: @ByteCommander the question is about the functionality of `systemd` which is used by both Ubuntu 16.04 and and Arch Linux to handle power management functions.